# Geometry generator and calling an expression from a custom function

Tags: qgis, qgis-custom-function

I am using geometry generator symbol layer type and some expressions that makes the result a line that is shorter then the original line.

The expression works and looks like this:

```
make_line(line_interpolate_point($geometry,10),line_interpolate_point($geometry,35))
```

However I would like to make my own function that makes it easier to do this operation. Inside the function I am trying to use the make_line expression but this results in an error in the expressions panel when using the function.

My function looks like this:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def smallerline(geometry,value1, feature, parent):
tmpline = make_line(line_interpolate_point(geometry,value1),line_interpolate_point(geometry,value1))

return tmpline
```

I'm using the function in the expression tab but there's an eval error that says "Eval Error:
global name 'make_line' is not defined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up expression syntax and python syntax.

The function you write is in python. Python does not understand the expression syntax.

You need to find a matching function in the pyqgis API to make the line shorter.

Looking at the sourcecode of the interpolate expression function it uses `lineGeom.interpolate(distance)`

make_line creates a new line (`lineString = QgsLineString()`) and then loops over the vertices and calls `lineString.addVertex( vertex )`.

Puttin the pieces together is left as an exercise for the reader.